# Encrypting a string with Cobol

Tags: string, encryption, cobol

I am debugging an old Cobol program, used for encryption purposes of different strings. (1.) Could someone explain to me what does SPACE X 'CB' stand for?

```
    ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.                                        
     SPECIAL-NAMES.                                               
     CLASS LATIN IS                                          
                "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"             
                "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" SPACE X'CB'.
```

Later on this code is being used to apply a relocation of every letter in the string, 4 places to the right of the alphabet. Some symbols keep popping in the encrypted string that I think have something to do with the EBCDIC characters but (2.) I cannot understand the exact connection between the string letters and the output symbols..

```
 IF STRING IS LATIN
  IF (FUNCTION ORD(first letter of string) + 4) <= FUNCTION ORD("Z") 
   MOVE FUNCTION CHAR(FUNCTION ORD(first letter of string) + 4)    
     TO NEWSTRING(I:1)
```

If the string "JOHNSMITH" would be taken as input then the output would be :

```
 OUTPUT --> NÀ±RWQàXÀ
```

Comment: [EBCDIC](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/xl-fortran-aix/16.1.0?topic=appendix-ascii-ebcdic-character-sets) has different values for the letters of the alphabet than ASCII.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Ok I get that, but, after reviewing the EBCDIC character set, I still don't understand the correlation between  O and À (for example)

Comment: The letter O is 214.  Adding 4 gives 218, which is undefined on the EBCDIC chart I'm looking at.

Comment: There is a second translation, that from EBCDIC to the character set used for the device you are viewing. That translation involves a code page. In any case, the problem is not to "understand the correlation," but to replicate the results of the old program in the new environment. I suggest creating a map (on paper) of what the results should be and use `INSPECT ... CONVERTING` to provide the same mapping of characters as before.

Comment: @RickSmith I don't know what the result should be. I just know what the result is and trying to understand why

Answer (score 3):

. Some weird symbols keep popping in the encrypted string that I think have something to do with the definition of the class?

**No** it is probably related to **EBCDIC**. Letters are not continuous in EBCDIC  like in ASCII, Letters are arranged as

```
a->i
   gap
j->r
   gap
s->z
```

*EBCDIC* is a family of Encodings (there is US EBCDIC, UK EBCDIC, German EBCDIC etc). What is in the `gap` is going to depend on which *EBCDIC variant* you are using. Any translation (e.g. EBCDIC --> ASCII) will further confuse the situation.

see [EBCDIC](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/xl-fortran-aix/16.1.0?topic=appendix-ascii-ebcdic-character-sets) or for IBM037 see https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/charsets/IBM037

So adding 4 to `O` throws it into the Gap, same with `H`.

The

```
IF STRING IS LATIN
```

is probably testing if the character Alphabetic, space or X'CB'

Comment: 1. So what does X'CB' stand for? 2. Getting H as an example with its ordinal inn EBCDIC being 200, what will come as the encrypted output as its is 'thrown into the gap' ? is the output some random symbol?

Comment: *So what does X'CB' stand for?* Possibly "`Ë`" (Latin Capital Letter E With Dieresis).

Comment: @AlkisKo see my updated answer. Basically it will depend on which EBCDIC variant you are using. Any EBCDIC --> ASCII will also confuse things further. For CP037 (IBM037), the conversion of H will possibly give (Latin Capital Letter O With Dieresis). See https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/charsets/IBM037 Run the program with all possible values and see what comes out

Comment: I still don't understand the use of X'CB' as  the fist part of my question. But you have mostly covered the second part, thankyou!

Comment: X'CB' is specifying a specific character, I would need to know the actual encoding to know what it is. If it is IBM037 (US EBCIDC) it should be this character https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00F4

Comment: @AlkisKo - *I still don't understand the use of X'CB' ...* If the program originated on a PC, the `X'CB'` may be a "backdoor" code to bypass "sign-in." It is a value that can be entered from the keyboard with multiple key presses, if one knows how and knows the value to be entered. Only the developer of the program would know the value and when to use it.

Answer (score 1):

If you *encrypt* a string you should *not* expect the result to consist of displayable or printable characters only, unless the encryption algorithm specifically states this.

The purpose of encryption is to hide the content. Unencrypting should bring back the original string. The encrypted string may contain just any value from 0 to 255 in any byte. Its the encryption algorithm which defines the relation between unencrypted, displayable characters and the encrypted counterpart.

Answer (score 0):

The x'CB' is just another way to define a entry in the class. Hex instead of character. If you are using the Latin code page you could do the following.
Class Latin is
X'414243CB'.

That give you same as
Class Latin is
'ABCE'.  The E is the (Latin Capital Letter E With Dieresis)